# PHP HTML div styled table rendering class: wrong indentation

Tags: php, html, class, oop

I am writing a class that renders `div` styled tables. The rendered table structure is as follows:

```
<div class="table">
    <!-- title, column headers -->
    <div class="table-body">
        <div class="table-row">
            <div class="table-row-cell">data11</div>
            <div class="table-row-cell">data12</div>
            <div class="table-row-cell">data13</div></div> <!-- this -->
        <div class="table-row">
            <div class="table-row-cell">data21</div>
            <div class="table-row-cell">data22</div>
            <div class="table-row-cell">data23</div></div> <!-- and this -->
    </div>
    <!-- footer -->
</div>
```

If you take a look, `<div>` closing tags for table rows should be in a new line correctly indented but that is not happening.

This is how I build the `div`'s:

```
public function get(): string
{
    // some code and loops

    $row_build .= $this->getHtmlDiv(
                            $html_cell_class,
                            $cell_data ?? "",
                            $this->html_attributes['cell'],
                            3
                        );
    // more code
}

private function getHtmlDiv(
    string $class,
    string $content = "",
    array $attrs = [],
    int $tabcount = 0
): string {
    $output = "\n" . str_repeat("    ", $this->tabs + $tabcount) . "<div";

    $output .= " class='$class'";

    foreach ($attrs as $attr => $value) {
        $output .= " $attr='$value'";
    }

    $output .= ">";
    $output .= $content;
    $output .= "</div>"; // <- here something should be done: what? IDK
    return $output;
}
```

I tried some alternatives and the closest I could get is this code right before `return $output;`:

```
if (substr($output, -2) !== "\n") {
    $output .= "\n" . str_repeat("    ", $this->tabs + $tabcount - 1);
}
```

that renders:

```
<div class='table-row'>
                
    <div class='table-row-cell'>data21</div>
                
    <div class='table-row-cell'>data22</div>
                
    <div class='table-row-cell'>data23</div>

</div>
```

Any ideas or suggestions on how to do it will be greatly welcome.

Thanks in advance for your time.

PS: if further code/explanation is needed, let me know and will append it to the original question.

Comment: I have to question why you aren't just using a `<table>`

Comment: Does it work if you put the last `</div>` in each row on their own line?

Comment: @Rob I use `div`'s because it suits my needs, because I can do it and because I don't like `<table>`. I'm sorry: I didn't get your second comment. How would that be?

Comment: I think you just need to put `\n` before the closing tag
`$output .= "\n</div>";`

Comment: @TimR tried that and it gets worst. `</div>`'s jump to next line without indentation

Comment: I took a closer look at your code and suspect that `$content` contains `<div class='table-row-cell'>`  and your question is how to indent only the closing tag for `<div class="table-row">`. If so, would this output the desired result? `$output .= "\n        </div>";`

Comment: `<table>` is semantically correct usage here. I hope you aren't avoiding it cause you read it's bad because it isn't for everything.

Comment: You said you have `</div></div>` in two places. I want you to try and put the second `</div>` on its own line and try that.

Comment: @TimR tab count is not hardcoded

Comment: @Rob the `div`'s are generated in `getHtmlDiv()`, and there is only one closing tag, so I still don't get where are you suggesting to put that second `</div>`. And as I said I'm doing it this way because I can and suits my needs (I know `<table>` is a valid tag).

Comment: _"and the closest I could get is this code right before return $output;"_ - that does not even _contain_ the closing `</div>` tag, all you are doing there is output an additional line that contains _only_ whitespace. `$output .= "</div>"; // <- here something should be done: what? IDK` - how about, the _exact same_ thing you also did for the opening tag? You want both of those at the same indentation level - so output the same amount of whitespace before both of them then?

Comment: If `$output = "\n" . str_repeat("    ", $this->tabs + $tabcount) . "<div";` got you the correctly indented opening tag, then `$output = "\n" . str_repeat("    ", $this->tabs + $tabcount) . "</div>";` should give you the proper corresponding closing tag, no?

Comment: @CBroe if I do the exact same thing I get each and every `</div>` in a new line although correctly indented.

Comment: If you want only _some_ closing div tags on a new line, but not all of them - then you need to find a way to let your script know, which ones those "some" actually are. For example, you could perhaps base this on the `$class` value here.

Comment: @CBroe I thought of that approach but dismissed it because `$class` can be a user defined value and for that I should turn 10 method variables into class properties or modify a class constant (unidimensional array) into a multi array). I was just thinking of adding a new parameter to `getHtmlDiv()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it adding a new parameter to `getHtmlDiv()`. This new parameter, `$add_newline` (`false` by default) is a flag that tells when to add a new line and tabs.

The function:

```
private function getHtmlDiv(
    string $class,
    string $content = "",
    array $attrs = [],
    int $tabcount = 0,
    bool $add_newline = false
): string {
    $output = "\n" . str_repeat("    ", $this->tabs + $tabcount) . "<div";

    $output .= " class='$class'";

    foreach ($attrs as $attr => $value) {
        $output .= " $attr='$value'";
    }

    $output .= ">";
    $output .= $content;

    if ($add_newline) {
        $output .= "\n" . str_repeat("    ", $this->tabs + $tabcount);
    }

    $output .= "</div>";

    return $output;
}
```

The call:

```
// this output is correct
$row_build .= $this->getHtmlDiv(
                        $html_cell_class,
                        $cell_data ?? "",
                        $this->html_attributes['cell'],
                        3
                    );

// and when I need a newline
$body_build .= $this->getHtmlDiv(
                $html_row_class,
                $row_build,
                $this->html_attributes['row'],
                2,
                true
            );
```